# Google new algorithm: My company have a 40 sites with different domains that some of their articles appears in my main website

Tags: seo, google-search, canonical-url, multiple-domains

My company have a 40 sites with different domains that some of their articles appears in my main website with reference to their source.

Our articles write by high level processionals in the field that they write about - we also pay them high salary.

In recent google algorithm change my main site rating down very seriously.

**What should we do to restore company main site google rating?**

our solution and ideas that not working well:

1. rel="canonical" to source website (we already have it before google change without results)
2. meta "original-source" but not have rating influence (we already have it before google change without results)

Edit::
maybe we should delete rel="canonical" from main website articles that refer to our other small websites
(because this articles in main website not indexed in google)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using rel="canonical" and the "original-source" meta tag then it sounds like you're one of the innocent victims of Google's update. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be anything you can do but wait as Google continues to improve their algorithm. In the meantime do what always seems to make Google happy: try to get some quality links to the articles.

**Update**

Always use rel="canonical" when it is appropriate. It's not a tool you use when you want to. It's a tool to use when there is duplicate content and you need to specify the the "main" source of that content. Put it on all of the duplicate content pages and make sure it points to the one you want to rank well. Don't play with it for SEO purposes. You'll only make things worse.